# UWP project (developed in VS2017) compile error in release mode (ILC error ILC1300)

Tags: compilation, uwp, visual-studio-2017

vs2017 output message:
LOGGERBASEDEXECTASK : ILC error ILC1300: Error while copying file 'G:\trunk\test\obj\ARM\Release\ilc\intermediate\Native\Test.dll' to 'G:\trunk\test\bin\ARM\Release\ilc\Test.dll': The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

Sometimes it can compile successfully, but sometimes it can not.

What happened  and What should  I do?

Thank you.

Comment: Disable your installed anti-malware product and try again.

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to the automatic protection of third-party security software. The deletion of some third-party software solves the problem.